# Is 'maximum pin current' on a TP4056 applicable to battery charging or to powering the load?

Tags: datasheet, microchip

I am buying this [Li-ion charger](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005003585993852.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.22.2e2b79d28QGWJ6&gatewayAdapt=glo2nld). It has pins for the battery and the output.

The main chip is a [TP4056 voltage regulator](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf). It regulates voltage from 5V to 4.2V to charge up a 18650 Li-ion battery. It states that the maximum BAT pin current will be 1.2 A. The battery must give 2A to the load. Is this sufficient? Because is the BAT circuit only used for charging? (The datasheet doesn't state a maximum output current.)

Comment: Does the battery roar? (lol)  Yes this is sufficient, but do not load while charging , else the CV mode may not cutoff. CC = 1.2A then CV=4.2 until I_chg< 5%~10% of CC